# Change tab TabLayoutPanel causes flicker

Tags: gwt

When I change a tab in `TabLayoutPanel` it moves up to position 0,0 and then returns back causing a flicker. I've tested that in IE9, I guess it must have something to do with the way a layout the screen, any ideas under what conditions should happen?

Comment: Unless someone saw exactly the same behavior, we may need to see your code before we can help.

Comment: @Andrei Volgin: Inside the tab is a dataGrid with hundreds of rows. I was shoewing all the rows but now I added paging of 100 and the flickering is gone.